# How to add members to trello board? (using rails app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, trello

I'm using ruby trello gem for my rails app. I need to add members to the created trello board. How can this be realized? I create board like this:

```
board = Trello::Board.create(
    name: BOARD_NAME,
    description: BOARD_DESC
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes you are using the [ruby-trello gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-trello/versions/2.2.0) at version 2.2.0.

First, instantiate your board. We will use your example here, but you could also [find an existing board](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-trello/2.2.0/Trello%2FBoard%2Efind):

```
board = Trello::Board.create(
    name: BOARD_NAME,
    description: BOARD_DESC
  )
```

Second, [instantiate a member](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-trello/2.2.0/Trello%2FMember%2Efind). You will need to provide `id_or_username` for this part:

```
member = Trello::Member.find(id_or_username)
```

Third, [add the member to the board](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-trello/2.2.0/Trello%2FBoard:add_member). You can use any of `:admin`, `:normal`, or `:observer` depending on the permissions the user should have:

```
board.add_member(member, :normal)
```

This operation does not require a separate call to [`save`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-trello/2.2.0/Trello%2FBoard:save) as it does not modify the fields of the board; it calls the API directly.

Comment: Can I use email instead of id_or_username ?

Comment: According to the gem documentation, no.